# vuejs 3 composition API

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

Anyone know why the variable number doesn't display the latest value when click on it? I tried using onMounted, but didn't seem to do anything. When I clicked on the paragraph it always displays 1. I expect it to display the latest number added. Any ideas?

```
<script setup>

  import TheWelcome from '@/components/TheWelcome.vue'
  import { onMounted, ref  } from 'vue'
  import axios from "axios"

  let number = 1; 
    
  function getCurrentNumber() {
    
    number++;

    console.log(number)
  }

</script>


<template>

  <main>
    <TheWelcome />
  </main>
  <p @click="getCurrentNumber">Hello, this is a test to display {{number}}</p>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const number = ref(1); 

function getCurrentNumber() {
  number.value++
  console.log(number.value)
}
</script>


<template>
  <p @click="getCurrentNumber">Hello, this is a test to display {{ number }}</p>
</template>
```

Here is a [working example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: thank you so much! The const keyword confuses me. I thought const means the variable number can't changed? I guessed Vue.js const has a different meaning.

Comment: @amarankes `const number` prevents `number` itself from being assigned a new value, but that doesn't apply to its subproperties.